# How to use git for setting up a component based project

Tags: node.js, git, mongodb, git-submodules

I'm planning to design a platform which will have a structure as follows.

- Root

  - Common
  - module_1
  - module_2
  - ...
  - module_N

This is a node/express/mongodb based plaform. As per my understanding, i can use git sub modules, Which allows to add more modules in future and handle each module as a independent project inside the main project. However i'm wondering is it possible to pull selected modules (eg: common,auth and module_2) without checking out all the modules in the main project, which will be used to develop a new application.

Is there any other way to organize a node project while maintaining my requirements? Appreciate any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

In git submodule, each submodule is using independent repository, whose URL is specified when you use `git submodule add` command to add submodules, by this, you can check out each submodule and operate on it independently.

Another tool you can use to manage multiple modules is [Repo](https://source.android.com/source/developing.html), which google developed and use it to manage Android source code.

Comment: Is it possible to pull the project along with selected sub modules ?

Comment: @aravindaM, you can `cd` to sudmodule folder and run any git command as you like, including `git pull`.

Comment: Let say i have this platform with ten twenty modules and i don't want to pull each module individually. I meant that is it possible to pull modules using a list of module names or similar way if i use git sub modules.

Comment: @aravindaM, Every submodule you added will be listed up in .submodule file in your worktree. you can use `git submodule foreach` to batch process all submodules. Please run `git submodule --help` for more details.

Comment: @aravindaM search for 'git submodule update --name <submodule-name>'

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Each submodule of the main repo is only a pointer to commit SHA is the sub repo. You can change develop each sub module seperatly and then change the 'pointer' (SHA) of an individual sub module to a specific commit/branch/tag

Here is a short demo:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJpwdJEO8iI